# Google Maps Geocoding API IP Address

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Currently I use Google Maps GeoCoding API to get location latitude and longitude from given address. However, the maps doesn't rendered correctly. 
I check on the browser console and got following error "API keys with referer restrictions cannot be used with this API"

After check on google search, one of the recommendation is to change the API Key restriction to IP Address restriction.

But since the Geocoding API call is called from the browser, I assume the IP addresses I should registered in Google Console Platform is visitor IP Addresses. Is that correct ? Is anyone experience to set the IP Address restriction successfully ?

Thank you.

Comment: Don't use web services (which are those that can be restricted by IP address) from the browser.

Comment: Why can't you use the built in [Geocoder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) in the Google Maps Javascript API v3?

Comment: @geocodezip Thank you for your advice. Do you mean using Maps JavaScript API to get latitude and longitude ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[Geocoding Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding)** (as mentioned by @geocodezip) when you are trying to geocode an address in the client-side. The behavior, parameters and results of this two APIs are the same.

**Sample address:** 1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA

**Geocoding Service sample demo:** Please check this [link](https://jsbin.com/fuxeqiw/edit?html,output)

```
geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {})
```

**Geocoding API sample request:** https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Compare the results! :)

Please note that for web service requests, you'll have to make sure that the address string you are trying to send is properly [URL-encoded](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

Happy coding!